# Stripe integration with composer not working on live server same works for localhost

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe using composer and passing values from previous payment file to stripe page and its working fine on local and creating payment on stripe user dashboard with custom values passed from files.While in live server with same secret key and publishable key getting error.And i have passed  \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false); before charge api it's still giving same error any help must be appreciated.

Stripe code:

```
function my_theme_send_email() {
    if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
   $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $card_num = $_POST['card_num'];
   $card_cvc = $_POST['cvc'];
   $card_exp_month = $_POST['exp_month'];
   $card_exp_year = $_POST['exp_year'];
   $tutorName = $_POST['selectedTutor']; 
   $Subject = $_POST['slectedSubject'];
   $selectedDates = $_POST['slectedDates'];
   $selectedPrice = $_POST['slectedPrice']; 
   $priceplan = $_POST['packageName'];
   $tutorid = $_POST['tutor_id'];
   $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
   $currency_switcher = $_POST['currencyswitcher'];
    include( get_template_directory() . 'STRIPE/init.php'); 
    include( get_template_directory() . 'STRIPE/vendor/autoload.php'); 
   //set api key
    $stripe = array(
     "secret_key"      => "sk_test_Nf2k88X8CCoqJrkXwUft89xR",
      "publishable_key" => "pk_test_1Lc32jHzjANsBUyPydlZ6iKK"
    );

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_Nf2k88X8CCoqJrkXwUft89xR');

    //add customer to stripe
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'email' => $email,
        'source'  => $token
    ));
     //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($customer);

    //item information
    $itemName = $Subject;
    $itemNumber = "PS123456";
  // $currency = $_POST['currencyswitcher'];
    $orderID = "SKA92712382139";

    //charge a credit or a debit card
    \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount'   => $_POST['packageName'],
        'currency' => $_POST['currencyswitcher'],
        'description' => $itemName,
        'metadata' => array(
            "order_id" => "SKA92712382139"
             )
    ));
   //echo "<pre>";
   // print_r($charge);



    //retrieve charge details
    $chargeJson = $charge->jsonSerialize();

    //check whether the charge is successful
    if($chargeJson['amount_refunded'] == 0 && empty($chargeJson['failure_code']) && $chargeJson['paid'] == 1 && $chargeJson['captured'] == 1){
        //order details 
        $amount = $chargeJson['amount'];
        $balance_transaction = $chargeJson['balance_transaction'];
        $currency = $chargeJson['currency'];
        $status = $chargeJson['status'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        //include database config file
      global $wpdb;

        //insert tansaction data into the database
       $sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_stripe_orders(name,student_id,tutor_id,tutor_name,email,card_num,card_cvc,card_exp_month,card_exp_year,item_name,item_number,item_price,item_price_currency,paid_amount,paid_amount_currency,package_plan,txn_id,order_id,payment_status,created,booked_date,modified) VALUES('".$name."','".$student_id."','".$tutorid."','".$tutorName."','".$email."','".$card_num."','".$card_cvc."','".$card_exp_month."','".$card_exp_year."','".$itemName."','".$itemNumber."','".$priceplan."','".$currency."','".$amount."','".$currency."','".$priceplan."','".$balance_transaction."','".$orderID."','".$status."','".$date."','".$selectedDates."','".$date."')");
        $insert =  $wpdb->query($sql);

        //if order inserted successfully
        if($insert && $status == 'succeeded'){
            $statusMsg = "<h2>The transaction was successful.</h2><h4>Order ID: {$last_insert_id}</h4>";
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Transaction has been failed";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = "Transaction has been failed";
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = "Form submission error.......";
}

//show success or error message
 $statusMsg;
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_send_email' );
```

Comment: You did not share the error you're getting, it's going to be hard to find a fix without it. Based on your `setVerifySslCerts` use I suppose it might be a TLS error though. If that's the case it might be that your live server does not support sending TLS1.2 requests. More info on https://stripe.com/blog/completing-tls-upgrade

Comment: i am getting 500 internal error. After using setVerifySslCerts and before using this function getting same error.